# Finding shoe size element with selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, size, element

Hello I'm pretty new to Selenium and I'm trying to figuere out how to click a button which changes the selected shoe size on footlocker.com. Here is [the product page I'm using for testing](https://www.footlocker.de/de/p/nike-bruin-hyperfeel-herren-schuhe-8811?v=314521665704#!searchCategory=herren/schuhe/canvasskate).

I click on the USA tab for sizing and then I would like to click on a size but i cant figure out how to find the specific li element.

```
<li class="fl-product-size--item" data-form-field-target="SKU" data-form-field-base-css-name="fl-product-size--item" data-form-field-value="314521665704105" data-form-field-unselect-group="" data-testid="fl-size-314521665704-44_5" data-product-size-select-item="314521665704105"> 
44,5</li>
```

Sorry if I did anything wrong while posting. I'm new here.

Comment: Please post the `HTML` Snippet and your `locator` that you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Firebug extension in Firefox to find your element. Then copy the XPath from there and use `driver.FindElement(By.XPath("xpath goes here"));`

To find all elements on the page by the list tag, you can use `driver.FindElements(By.TagName("li"))`

To find the specific element by its class name, you can use `driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("fl-product-size--item"))`

Comment: I got It to work using `driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[contains(@class, 'fl-acc--content-container')]/ul/li[contains(., '10.5')]")).Click();` . Thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

To find that specific li element using its specific class selector, your best option is to use a css selector:

```
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("li.fl-product-size--item""));
```

Hope this helps