# Python Selenium button click

Tags: python, selenium, web-crawler

I am trying to click a button to show more comments on a discusson thread on http://disqus.com/

The HTML looks like following:

`<div class="load-more" data-role="more" style="">
    <a href="#" data-action="more-posts" class="btn load-more__button">Show more</a>
</div>`

I have tried using the xPath from the button like following:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome("/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver")
driver.get(url)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('''//*[@id="posts"]/div[3]/a''').click()
```

But I get the NoSuchElement exception.

What is the proper way of clicking a button with that type of HTML?

UPDATE: Worked when I switched to a specific iFrame:

```
 driver.switch_to.frame('myID')
```

Then loaded by class name:

`element = driver.find_element_by_class_name('load-more')
element.click()`

NOTE: That the `click()` did not work when it was performed on the same line like `driver.find_element_by_class_name('load-more').click()`

Comment: Proper is `//a[text()="Show more"]`, but this link could be located inside `iframe`, so you can handle it only after `driver.switch_to_frame(iframe_id)`

Comment: You may need to wait for element to be clickable by using `element_to_be_clickable`

Comment: Sometimes with Selenium it pays to try a few different methods of selecting your element. Some pages work better with one method than another. Have you tried `find_elements_by_class_name("btn load-more__button")` ?

Answer (score 0):

Xpath should be a last resort for finding elements. For your case, I would try

`driver.find_element_by_class_name("load-more__button"));`

Using `btn load-more__button` won't work as compound classNames aren't valid.

If that still doesn't work, Id recommend using css selectors before Xpath.

However, if none of these options work, and your Xpath is still not working, you should use the firebug add on for Firefox to ensure the Xpath you are using is correct.

Here's some of my other answers that may help you get started with Firebug:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/38980488/3537915

https://stackoverflow.com/a/38723782/3537915

https://stackoverflow.com/a/38744577/3537915